# Two subsets of a group commute. Do their symmetric closures also commute?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group.  The symmetric closure of a subset $S\subset G$ is the subset $\hat S=S\cup S^{-1}$.  Two subsets $S,T\subset G$ commute if $ST=TS$.

I can show that if $S$ and $T$ are two subsets of $G$ such that $ST=TS$ and $T=\hat T$ then $\hat S\hat T=\hat T\hat S$.  Is it possible to remove the assumption $T=\hat T$?  In other words, if $S$ and $T$ are any subsets that commute do their symmetric closures also commute?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. With a computer search you soon find counterexamples. For example, the claim is false with $G=A_4$, $S= \{1, (1,3,2),(1,4,3)\}$, $T=\{(1,2,3),(1,4,2),(1,3)(2,4)\}$.

Comment: Thank you Derek.  I was trying to find an example by hand and getting nowhere.